Apache rewrite engine - Removing PHP extension, getting query string, and appending trailing slash
I recently started working with the rewrite engine and asked for help on removing the PHP extension and adding a trailing slash to URLs. A perfectly working solution was provided by anubhava here. For a quick reference, the configuration file is provided below:
.htaccess
RewriteEngine On

# removes .php and adds a trailing /
# i.e. to externally redirect /path/file.php to /path/file/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=307,NE,L]

# adds a trailing slash to non files 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=307,NE]

# internally rewrites /path/file/ to /path/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]

This configuration works as intended for URLs like:
https://example.com/test.php
https://example.com/test
https://example.com/test/

The URLs above are all rewritten to:
https://example.com/test/

So far so good, except that if the PHP file contains a query string, it works a little differently than I would like. For example, if the URL is:
https://example.com/test.php?lang=en&id=3

Then it is rewritten to:
https://example.com/test/?lang=en&id=3

Unfortunately, I did not anticipate this problem, which is causing me issues because I cannot capture the query string in the PHP file below.
test.php
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
?>

To resolve this, I need a method to capture the PHP query string. I think rewriting the URL to https://example.com/test?lang=en&id=3/ could work. However, I'm open to alternative solutions.
Edit: Given the complexity of the problem, the trailing slash is optional, but I would like to remove the PHP extension and be able to capture the query string.

If you rewrite to https://example.com/test?lang=en&id=3/ you only make id to be 3/ That makes no sense. It would help if you'd explain WHY you are doing all this. Are you just trying to hide the ".php" extension? Then why the trailing slash? only if the file does not exist... But if you remove the .php of course it won't find the file, so it will always add a slash. The last part adds the .php again... But how can that work if you just added a slash? I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve exactly and especially: why.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f - can't say for sure, if %{REQUEST_FILENAME} will actually contain test here, when you requested test/ - I think that test might probably fail here? And that /test/ actually invokes test.php, might be due to MultiViews being activated, rather than due to your rewriting attempts. What happens, when you remove RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f?

@Roemer Yes, the primary purpose is to hide the PHP extension, but the trailing slash is optional, I would say.

@CBroe By removing that line,  the output remains exactly the same as before.

And what happens, when you add Options -MultiViews at the very top?

@CBroe The output still remains the same.

Considering our discussion in the comments, this (though only very roughly tested on a flawed online htaccess tester) should work.
Noticed I removed the adding of the '/' exceptif there is a real directory. Adding a / has a significant meaning for an URL (it refers to a directory, not to a file!) so just adding it for beauty makes no sense, it is exactly why everything became complicated and went wrong.
If you use routing (for instance in Laravel or another platform) of course you can do with the url whatever you want, but since you don't seem to be, and seem to need the URL match to a file on your server, you just really don't want to add random slashes.
RewriteEngine On

# removes .php externally
# i.e. to externally redirect /path/file.php to /path/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=307,NE,L]

# adds .php internally -- we still need to find the file!
# i.e. invisably to the user redirect /path/file to /path/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


Thank you for your answer. I tried your configuration but when I entered the URL, it remained exactly the same. For example, https://example.com/test.php?lang=en&id=3 was not rewritten.

I simplified and tested the solution. Still no trailing '/', you need a pro to make that work. Even the example I could find online just didn't work. And it makes me crinch.

Just to be clear: above solution (which is edited compared to the last time) works.

The RewriteRule directive allows for a QSA flag that copies the query string to the rewritten URL.

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

So your [L] flags should be something like [L,QSA].
For additional doc, you can find the list of available flags for the RewriteRule directive.
I found this out by reading the Fat-Free Framework .htaccess sample.
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(app|dict|ns|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA] <------------------------------------ HERE
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]


Thank you for your answer, I appreciate your efforts. I tried to replace the last [L] flag with [L,QSA], then I also tried to replace all of them, but the result is the usual https://example.com/test/?lang=en&id=3 like before.

Adrian, that "usual' result is the only result that makes sense consifering you want to end with '/'. Remember , ending with '/' you are pointing to a DIRECTORY, not a file. The query parameters always come last, so you are pointing to https://example.com/test/index.php?lang=en&id=3. Step off of the idea to end with a slash. You are trying to put a square peg in a round hole.
